# Package "Shell Foundation" requires setting "Start" in Component "themeservice_amd64" set to the value "2" error in WES7 Toolkit

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-embedded-7

I have encountered a sophisticated problem as I am trying to build a Windows Embedded Standard 7 bootable image for my enterprise thin client. As I am not familiar with and/or not willing to use `sysprep` capture and deploy method I prefer doing everything directly in the Windows Embedded Standard 7 Toolkit. However, when I made my answer file and went on to validate it, I found a *warning* that said:

`Package "Shell Foundation" requires setting "Start" in Component "themeservice_amd64" set to the value "2"` .
After a second validation it become an *error*.

FYI, I am trying to set the `themeservice_amd64\Start` component setting to `4`, to disable the Windows 7 Basic theme and enable only the Windows Classic one, as my client needs minimum performance overhead. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My flawed answer file is here: https://pastebin.com/f5tM9dk1